# Creating a multi-colored JLabel in java with the help of html

Tags: java, html, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I am trying to change the color of a part of my JLabel to a specific color.I am trying to make it so that "Blue Wins" in Blue Wins: 0 becomes the color blue, I know that I should use html function and that the function should look something like this new `JLabel("<html>Blue Wins: 0 <font color='Blue Wins'>blue</font></html>"));`. But I am not sure if that's how it should look and more importantly where I should place this function in my code ( the GUI section and not the logic section)

These Two snippets of code are the ones connected to the Jlabel and the Gui part of the colors and fonts of it.

```
JLabel infoLabel;
    JLabel XWinCounter = new JLabel("X Wins: 0");
    JLabel OWinCounter = new JLabel("O Wins: 0");
    GameLogic gameLogic;
```

---

```
infoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,1));
        XWinCounter.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        XWinCounter.setOpaque(true);
        infoPanel.add(XWinCounter);
        infoPanel.add(OWinCounter);
        infoPanel.add(infoLabel);
        getContentPane().add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[Gui Jlabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABqUT.png)

This is how the GUI with the Jlabel currently looks, The whole foreground color is blue, I only want the Blue Wins: Part to be blue the : and 0 should remain the same color it is currently.

Comment: `<font color='Blue Wins'>` *"But I am not sure if that's how it should look"* No, it's definitely not. When having problems using HTML in Swing components, it is advisable to try it first as HTML in a browser, validate it using an HTML validation service etc. Don't just make stuff up and hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e need to add the HTML on the construcror of the JLabel, like this:

```
public class Answers {
    public static JFrame f = new JFrame("Colors");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel XWinCounter = new JLabel("<html>X Wins: <font color='blue'>0</font></html>");
        JLabel OWinCounter = new JLabel("<html>Y Wins: <font color='red'>0</font></html>");
        f.add(OWinCounter, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(XWinCounter, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```